# How to run awk -F\' '{print $2}' inside subprocess.Popen in Python?

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, awk, subprocess

I need to run a shell command inside subprocess.Popen in Python.

The command is:
$ virsh dumpxml server1 | grep 'source file' | awk -F\' '{print $2}'

The output is:
/vms/onion.qcow2

I'm having two challenges with the above command:

1) The command is inside a loop, and where you see 'server1', it is a variable that will have a server name.

2) Python is complaining about KeyError: 'print $2'

Here is what I have so far:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["virsh dumpxml {0} | grep 'source file' | awk -F\' '{print $2}'".format(vm)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

stdout = proc.communicate()[0]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using https://libvirt.org/python.html to access libvirt stuff directly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it's possible use libvirt directly from python, your problem is that `{` is the format string, and surrounds `print $2` in your `awk` script as well, so you have to escape those braces like

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["virsh dumpxml {0} | grep 'source file' | awk -F\\' '{{print $2}}'".format(vm)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout = proc.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, but I'm still getting an error: /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @GreenTeaTech Right you are, I had fixed this in my local attempts, but forgot to in my answer (though I have edited it to have that fix now).  The problem is with the `-F\'` in awk, python is "eating" the `\` so you need to escape it