# python run shell command with pipeline

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to run `ip -o -6 addr list | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1` in python2, and get the ipv6 addresses.  `os.system` does run the command, but the return value is 0 or 1.

I looked into `subprocess.call`, what are those `args` when command becomes complicated like with `|`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["ip -o -6 addr list | awk '{{print $4}}' | cut -d/ -f1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
ipv6_all = proc.communicate()[0]
```

Got the idea from [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900380/how-to-run-awk-f-print-2-inside-subprocess-popen-in-python?rq=1) Eric Renouf's answer.